# Xpath | how do I know if the current node has a specific class or not

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm extracting data using scrapy. I'm on a node getting info about sizes , based on classes , I've to mark that size available or not. 
I tried with this:

```
if size.xpath('./not([@class="sch-avaiable"])'):
            dictionary['out_of_stock'] = True
```

My understanding is , size is the pointing to current node , and if I use '.' this means the current node so the above expression will return the current node if it don't have sch-available class in it.

How do I use Xpath to know either current node has specific class or not?

Comment: you can check the count of particular class elements if it present

Comment: how ? previously I was using this
if 'sch-avaiable' not in size.xpath("@class").extract_first():
but I'm asked to move this 'not' inside xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct answer is

```
if size.xpath('self::*[not(contains(@class, "sch-avaiable"))]').extract()
```

this self:: worked